# Child collection empty when POSTing to OData v4 Web API action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

I've got a parent object with a child collection property of complex objects. When performing a POST to create a new record of this parent & it's related children, I can see in the `Post()` action that the parent is deserialized correctly, but that the child collection is empty.

The API project uses the following package versions for Web API & OData:
*Microsoft.AspNet.OData - v7.1.0*
*Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi - v5.2.7*

**Example models:**

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**OData configuration**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.Namespace = "NS";

    builder.EntitySet<Parent>("Parents")
        .EntityType
        .Expand(SelectExpandType.Automatic)
        .Filter().OrderBy().Select().Page();

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

**Controller definition**

```
public class ParentsController : ODataController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Parent model)
    {
        // process data from 'model' parameter here
    }
}
```

It's inside this `Post()` controller action that the collection is empty - i.e. `model.Children.Length` is equal to zero.

On the client-side, I'm using the *OData v4 Client Code Generator (v7.5.1)* extension to generate client proxy classes from the API metadata. The below snippet shows how the proxy objects are being created & passed to the API endpoint:

```
var apiModel = new Parent();
apiModel.Children.Load(new List<Child> { new Child { Name = "Test Child" } })

Container.AddToParents(apiModel);
await Container.SaveChangesAsync();
```

<s>I can confirm that the child objects are being passed to the API. It just seems like the API is not deserializing these into the collection for the action parameter.</s> Anyone know what may be causing this to happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Turns out the child collection wasn't actually get passed. The traffic I captured in Fiddler that showed the child array was getting fired by some errant test code in my client & not the OData v4 Client Code Generator proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the proxy generated by OData v4 Client Code Generator does not support deep inserts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312523/odata-v4-client-code-generator-how-to-do-deep-insert) Stackoverflow.com question gave me the correct terminology to search for, as it was answered in 2017 & I was looking to see if support has been added. Sadly it doesn't appear so, judging by [this](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/736) open issue on the team's GitHub.

For now, the only options seems to be to create the parent, then all the children, as two separate calls, or switch to a different library like RestSharp.